# if my answer is selected, can I still edit it?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer

If the questioner selects my answer as the correct one, can I still go and edit the answer or is it frozen?

Comment: why would you ask this here instead of just trying it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can edit it, and so can anyone with editing rights. Just because it was selected doesn't mean it can't be improved.

Answer (score 0):

When something is selected as the accepted answer, all it really does is provide a visual identifier which one the original question asker believes is the best answer or the answer that solves their problem, along with a 15 point bonus. There are absolutely no locking features on the checkmark (except you can't delete your answer...thanks Jon)

Comment: Not quite true - it's locked in that you (as the author) can no longer delete it.